# How can I approximate an algebraic segment using a Curve_2 of Arr_conic_traits_2?

Tags: computational-geometry, cgal

I am computing the plane bisector of two line segments (of type `RatKernel::Segment_2`) which can be composed by parabolic arcs, rays and line segments.

Using the `Arr_conic_traits_2<RatKernel, AlgKernel, NtTraits>` class I could easily create the parts that were parabolic arcs, and this was not a problem. As specified in the [reference](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Arrangement_on_surface_2/classCGAL_1_1Arr__conic__traits__2.html), the supporting curves of the arcs need to be of the form: `rx^2 + sy^2 + txy + ux + vy + w = 0` where all six coefficients need to be rational numbers. However, the endpoints of the arcs can be `Point_2` with algebraic coordinates.

The problem arises with the rays (which anyway had to be bounded to very long segments as the conic traits class only supports bounded curves) and the segments, because in order to connect them to the parabolic arcs, they
also need to have algebraic endpoints. This means that the supporting curve (a line) would have also algebraic coefficients, but this is not supported.

I really need all pieces of the bisector to be connected to each other, because approximating the segment parts with rational segments (and thus making the bisector pieces disconnected) appears to cause errors in other computation.

One idea was to approximate these segment bisector parts using almost flat curves; the problem is that I just have the two endpoints, and I can create a third point in the middle and move it slightly (it can therefore easily have rational coordinates) so that the curve passing through the three points would not be flat.
Having three points (two forcefully algebraic) I'd need to create a curve that satisfies them all and that has rational coefficients. Is this possible? Are there better solutions?

P.S.: Using another arrangement class such as `Arr_algebraic_segment_traits_2` would allow me to use unbounded rays, but if I understood correctly the endpoints of all curves would need to have as x coordinate an integer number, which is even a bigger problem.

Comment: URL is not found.

Comment: Sorry, somehow the description got mixed in the URL; corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `Arr_algebraic_segment_traits_2` after all.
The curves handled by this traits are the graph of the zero set of polynomials. The restriction is that the coefficients must be integral numbers, which implies that polynomials with rational coefficients can be handled as well. The coordinates of a point are real numbers.

To construct a real number and use it as a coordinate, do something like:

```
#include <CGAL/Algebraic_kernel_d_1.h>

typedef CGAL::Algebraic_kernel_d_1<Integer>             AK;
typedef AK::Polynomial_1                                Polynomial_1;

AK ak;
AK::Construct_algebraic_real_1 construct_algreal_1 =
  ak.construct_algebraic_real_1_object();
Polynomial_1 px = CGAL::shift(AK::Polynomial_1(1),1);
Algebraic_real_1 c = construct_algreal_1(px*px-2,1);
Point_2 p = construct_point(c, c);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
`Arr_algebraic_segment_traits_2` would work well to be able to have unbounded rays, however like `Arr_conic_traits_2` the curves can have coefficients that are at most `Rational`.
My problem is that the curves sometimes need to have `Algebraic` coefficients, because they are segments of bisectors and there might be square roots involved which might make the coefficients of the line `Algebraic`.

Comment: As you say, in this case neither Arr_conic_traits_2 nor Arr_algebraic_segment_traits_2 will help you. You need to develop your own traits. The code of Arr_conic_traits_2 is older than the code of  Arr_algebraic_segment_traits_2; thus, it is probably less efficient. However, it might be more simple and an easier starting point.

Comment: Developing my own traits could work, but it would need to support the construction of intersections of curves with algebraic coefficients, and I suspect that might be mathematically too intensive.

About  the class `Arr_algebraic_segment_traits_2`: I tried converting my code to using it, but on my IDE and also in the examples I saw that for the endpoints I have to provide an `x` coordinate, an `arcno` on the curve and the curve itself. The problem is that both on the IDE and on the examples it looked like this `x` coordinate could only be given as an `int`. Is that correct?

Comment: I believe it is incorrect. I've edited my answer above with a code excerpt that shows how to do it.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Thank you very much for your help! In the end I think the only way to obtain what I need for my program to work correctly is to develop an own traits class to use as a base.